# Issue with browser-side conversion SVG -> PNG

Tags: javascript, svg, browser, png

I'm writing a bookmarklet that is supposed to take a screenshot of an SVG chart and save it as a PNG image. I'm testing this with the latest Chrome browser.

Here is the URL of the page containing the chart: https://data.oecd.org/gdp/real-gdp-forecast.htm The chart I want to capture and save as PNG is the large one in the top half of the page. It can be identified by the CSS class `ddp-chart-inner`.

The code in the bookmarklet is here: https://pastebin.com/raw/cduvdC6e (pastebin because GitHub sets some CSP header that doesn't allow the code to be injected into another website).

```js
(function() {
    // this library is used for the download of the generated image
    var fileSaverUrl = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.2/FileSaver.min.js';

    var d = document, b = d.body, fs = d.createElement('script');
    fs.setAttribute('src', fileSaverUrl);
    fs.onload = function() {
        console.log('FileSaver loaded.');
        var canvas = d.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.height = '400';
        canvas.width = '700';
        b.appendChild(canvas);

        var image = d.createElement("div");
        image.id = 'png-container';
        b.appendChild(image);

        // this part comes from here: http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/8187844
        var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(d.getElementsByClassName('ddp-chart-inner')[0]);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
        var img = new Image();
        var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
        var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.querySelector('#png-container').innerHTML = '<img src="'+png+'"/>';
            // that's what I want... it downloads a file that doesn't look like the chart ...
            saveAs(png, 'test.png');
            DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
        };
        img.src = url;
    }
    b.appendChild(fs);  
}).call(this);
```

This code is loaded via this bookmarklet:

```js
javascript:(function(){ var d = document, b = d.body, s = d.createElement('script');    s.setAttribute('src', 'https://pastebin.com/raw/cduvdC6e?x=' + Math.random());    b.appendChild(s);}());
```

The result that I'm getting is this:

[image: sample PNG output]

One can just about recognise the X axis labels rotated 45 degrees, but other than that ...

Note that I've started initially using the [`html2canvas`](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) library but results weren't satisfying either.

Also, right now, no clean up is done such as removing the created elements, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having spoken to the developers, they said that the mix of HTML and SVG for these specific charts made it impossible to create the PNG client-side. It is indeed necessary to use puppeteer on the server to achieve what was asked.